# rails user authorisation on different projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

Currently I am workin on a rails app which has users and projects. Each user has a role of admin from the start, so they have full access on their projects. But a user1 can be assigned to other projects created by user2, so that means the user2 will select one users1, it will give him the role of moderator, on projectA.

I was thinking in creating a link table between user role and project, is this the best approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No i think you should model usergroups and assign new users to the adminGroup. Then you create the moderatorsGroup and add the user1 to the project as member of this group. So you have a matrix. Usersname | Project1 groups | Project2 groups.
This way you can have several roles in mutliple projects. Then you just have to keep the groups project specific.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I don't quite get what are you saying, can you please give me more details, I am quite a noob when comes to rails.

Comment: In your application you have users, projects and user's roles (i.e moderator). All you have to do for your solution is to modell these relations. You can do this, by giving the users memberships in groups, that represent their role. So user1 can be admin in project1, if you put him into the group of admins. And he can have a different role in another project. When you put user1 to the group of moderators for project2, he will have this role. I hope you understand this. So you have a matrix like this:
http://nopaste.info/a6941a5fdf.html